# How to query a range of values using graphql

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

My data models are sequelized and I am looking for a straightforward way to query graphql using from: and to: params to specify range.

Any syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using Sequelize as an underlying ORM, this functionality can be supported through Sequelize range operators. From http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/querying/#range-operators:

```
{
  createdAt: {
    $lt: new Date(),
    $gt: new Date(new Date() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
  }
}
// createdAt < [timestamp] AND createdAt > [timestamp]
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out ! Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Given that the reference and example is for a SQL ORM, and that the [GraphQL spec](http://facebook.github.io/graphql/October2016) makes no mention of `$gt` or `$lt`, how is this anything other than a fond fantasy?  And how in the world did it get three upvotes???

Comment: @peteb4ker is mistaken, GraphQL has NO such built-in operators. The 'lt' and 'gt' range operators he refers to are specific to SequelizeJS. This answer should be edited and/or downvoted.

Comment: edstaub/petri thanks for the valuable feedback.   Post updated to specifically call out Sequelize.